# std::tuple with reference fails to compile in clang, but not in gcc

Tags: c++, g++, language-lawyer, clang++

The following code:

```
using input_t = std::tuple<short, int&, const long&, const double>;
int b = 1;
int c = 2;
input_t t{0, b, c, 3};
```

Will fail to compile in `clang 9.0` but succeeds with `gcc 9.2`: https://godbolt.org/z/6CuEaf

`clang` will fail with the error:

```
In file included from <source>:2:

tuple:133:17: error: reference member '_M_head_impl' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object

        : _M_head_impl(std::forward<_UHead>(__h)) { }

                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

/tuple:218:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Head_base<2, const long &, false>::_Head_base<int &>' requested here

      _Base(std::forward<_UHead>(__head)) { }

      ^

/tuple:217:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Tuple_impl<2, const long &, const double>::_Tuple_impl<int &, int, void>' requested here

    : _Inherited(std::forward<_UTail>(__tail)...),

      ^

/tuple:217:4: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Tuple_impl<1, int &, const long &, const double>::_Tuple_impl<int &, int &, int, void>' requested here

/tuple:627:11: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::_Tuple_impl<0, short, int &, const long &, const double>::_Tuple_impl<int, int &, int &, int, void>' requested here

    : _Inherited(std::forward<_UElements>(__elements)...) { }

      ^

<source>:10:13: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::tuple<short, int &, const long &, const double>::tuple<int, int &, int &, int, true>' requested here

input_t t{0, b, c, 3};

        ^
```

Which one is correct here? I don't see anything that should result in exceeding the lifetime of `b` and `c`.

---

Comment: How do you want to bind `int` to `long` ? Temporary instance is created by promoting `int` to `long`, then this temp is bound to `const long&`. You have dangling reference. Add this line to the code: `std::cout << &c << std::endl;` and  `std::cout << &std::get<2>(t) << std::endl;` you will see two different addresses, but both should be the same. When `c` was long, these addresses would have the same values.

Comment: @rafix07 Ahhhhhh! Perfect. So is GCC wrong here? I guess so.

Comment: @rafix07 That's perfectly true, but it does not tell you if the compiler should reject the code or not at compile time. As long as you do not use `std::get<2>(t)` directly, you have no UB.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code:

```
struct X
{
   X(int i)
   {
      std::cerr << "constructed from " << i << std::endl;
   }
   ~X() { std::cerr << "destructed\n"; }
};

struct Y
{
   const X& ref_;
   Y(const X& ref) : ref_(ref)
   {
      std::cerr << &ref << std::endl;
   }
};

int main ()
{
   int i = 1;
   Y y(i);
   std::cerr << &y.ref_ << std::endl;
}
```

Its output is as follows:

```
constructed from 1
0x7fff6a0bb78b
destructed
0x7fff6a0bb78b
```

Live demo is [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/j87evP8mKgr3kc3w).

It kind-of simulates `std::tuple` with `Y` here. In `Y y(i)`, a parameter `ref` is bound to a temporary of type `X`. But this temporary is destructed as the lifetime of `ref` parameter is ended. Then, `ref_` becomes a dangling reference, as @rafix07 pointed out in a comment.

It therefore makes no sense to initialize a tuple member of a reference type in such a way that results in a binding to a temporary. The question is whether a compiler is required to issue a diagnostic here. I don't think it has to and I don't see any relevant information in [[tuple]](http://eel.is/c++draft/tuple).

It just says, regarding `forward_as_tuple`:

> Constructs a tuple of references to the arguments in `t` suitable for forwarding as arguments to a function. **Because the result may contain references to temporary objects, a program shall ensure that the return value of this function does not outlive any of its arguments**.

But the same wording is not present by the definition of `tuple` ("direct") constructor.

Comment: What you say here it's true but still, clang compiles this example without issue, so this does not answer the actual question, which is likely `tuple`-specific.

Comment: @Holt Agree, I realized that as well. Will try to dig a bit deeper and update my answer if I find out any relevant information.